# List of Different Directory Sizes

Tags: windows, scripting, directory

I have a list of folders on my network in a .txt, which are stored in different locations throughout the network. Looking for a tool or script to pull the size of those folders and output them to a txt/cvs files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@echo off
for /f %%d in (dirlist.txt) do (
   @echo %%d
   du -q %%d | findstr /B "Size.*disk"
   @echo.
)
```

You can get the du program from [Sysinternals Disk Usage](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896651)

Answer (score 2):

I think [Disk Usage](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896651) will do that for you.  At a minimum you can whip up a script that uses it to do what you want.